# Codeigniter Model: How to use values from a query for further calculations?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model, row

i have a function in a model with the following query, and i want to make some calculations with value1, value2 and value3 outside the query. how to get the values out of this result()?

```
function ($id,$username$) {

   $this->db->select("id,value1,value2,value3,value4");
   $this->db->from("table1");
   $this->db->where("username=$username and id = $id");
   $query=$this->get();
   $result = $query->result();

   $result['$testvalue'] = (value1 * value2/113) + value3;

return $result; }
```

can someone help? i already found out how to use values from a table, but not from a query!

ok now i know how to use row_array. 
i call the row_array in the controller

```
$data = $this->model_testmodel->testfunction($id, $username);

...

$this->load->view('pages/view_test', $data);
```

now i wanna know how the view would look like.
i tried many different ways.
in the moment i am stuck with ...

```
<?php foreach $data as $value: ?>
     <label>Value1:</label>
     <input type="text" name="value1" value="<?php echo $value['value1']; ?>">
     <label>Value2:</label>
     <input type="text" name="value2" value="<?php echo $value['value2']; ?>">
     ...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but i get two errors:

1. Message: Undefined variable: data
2. Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
function ($id,$username) 
{

   $this->db->select("id,value1,value2,value3,value4");
   $this->db->from("table1");
   $this->db->where(array('id'=>$id,'username'=>$username));
   $query=$this->db->get();
   $result = $query->row();

   $testvalue = (($result->value1 * $result->value2/113) + $result->value3);

   //test here 
   echo $testvalue;
 $res = array();
 $res['testvalue'] = $testvalue;
 $res['value1'] = $result->value1;
 $res['value2'] = $result->value2;
 $res['value3'] = $result->value3;

return $res; 
}
```

It returns $res as array.Easy to execute of you got problem comment.. if it works accept.Lets enjoy..

Then make a function call and accept array in a variable..like this..
first load model then make function call.from your controller

```
$this->load->model('model_name');

$data= $this->model_name->function_name($id,$username);
//Fetch returned array like this..
echo $data['testvalue']; 
echo $data['value1'];
//so on
```

Comment: thanks, but that would only return the testvalue, but i also need all the other values (value1, value2, value3, value4) and the testvalue.

Comment: thanks, i can see the value already in the echo test. now have to go on working on my controller. ;)

Comment: just out of curiosity, is there also a way to do it with result() instead of row() and address the field like $result['value1'] instead of $result->value1?

Comment: yes this is also possible. Use `result_array()` in the place of `result()`.

Comment: you mean $result = $query->result(); to $result = $query->result_array(); then i can use $result['value1'] in the calculation and i dont need to do $res = array();? rite?

Comment: use `row_array` instead of `result_array().

Comment: now ... Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::array_row()

Comment: sorry my fault!

Comment: ok looks good. can i still use the <?php foreach ($values as $value): ?> in the view then?

Comment: yes just send your `$data` to view from controller then apply loop.

Comment: in the controller i use $data['values'] = $this->model_testmodel->testfunction($id, $username); call the view with $this->load->view('pages/view_test', $data); and in the view i use the foreach as just mentioned and then i get the error: Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: not `$data['values']` just use `$data`. and in view `foreach($data as $value)`.

Comment: `$data= $this->model_testmodel->testfunction($id, $username);`

Comment: still doesnt work, i call the view and in the view i have the loop as u said. and call each value like this <?php echo $value->value1; ?> , but then i get error: Undefined variable: data

Comment: but the view gives me still the same error message at the line of the foreach loop.

Comment: actually two errors, the second one is Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: ok, managed to get a solution without foreach loop and just addressing the values like this: echo $value1!